# Gravity of RatingBar with custom rating drawables

Tags: android, ratingbar

I've set custom drawables to the RatingBar and seems that it's internal gravity became set to "top" (see screenshot, green is its background set to indicate its actual height)

[image]
Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rate_ll"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/reviews_tv"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/title_rate"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#0f0"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                            android:stepSize="1"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_star" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

rating_star.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_redstar" />

</layer-list>
```

Gravity is OK with default drawable.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and i just changed **android:minHeight** attribute of RatingBar. I hope it helps